# Collaborative Filtering using ALS

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

We are trying to use collaborative filtering mechanism for recommendations, implicit data, based on users are navigating to. Trying [ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) (using Spark) which makes sense here. All fine.

Now the model would be trained (every 6 hrs or so), all fine, and provide recommendation for a user.

Now what I am trying to understand - when the user clicks 'A' and the live recommendation that would be provided using the model, the model also needs to take into account the very recent click 'A' which the user has made.

That click 'A' would go into model training, whenever the model gets trained in the next 6 hrs. (but the user live recent recommendations cannot wait for 'A' to go into training and then come back, thats too late)

Wanted to understand, how to go about this.

Anshuk